# Changing a value from reference?

Tags: c#, variables, asynchronous, reference, loading

I'm trying to get picture to update by reference. I know where the issue is happening, but I'm curious if it is possible to do something like this in C# or not.

I'm making a system where people can do dialogues with pictures on the side, and am loading up a "loading" image while calling an async load of the picture (as it may be big and take a little while to load). All of that is working, I'm just curious if I can get away with using a variable of the picture to update the picture, or if I should reference the object (as the object may be one of three different depending on where the user is, but it always references a picture).

This is all pseudocode I tried to name as obviously as possible.

```
Class AsyncLoad()
{
Picture pic;
string location;

void AsyncLoadStart(string picLocation, Picture picRef)
{
    pic = picRef;
    location = picLocation;
    AsyncLoad();
}

void AsyncLoad()
{

    pic = picRef;
    Picture picLoading = PictureFromFile(picLocation);
    while (picLoading.IsLoad)
        Wait();
    pic = picLoading; //issue is here
}
}
```

The issue is that is simply drops the location of the old pic, and make pic reference picLoading. I'm just curious if there's a way to do what I want without reference to the object that pic is attached to.

Clarification : I am trying to update picRef when assinging picLoading to pic. I assume I have to save a reference to the object that picRef is assigned to, and update picRef directly. I am just curious if there is an alternate way, like how the ref keyword would work if this was not asynchronous.

Edit 2 : The program I'm using these graphics in kind of forces me to use 2 seperate methods to load, as I've clarified above - or else I would just have used the ref keyword. I updated the pseudocode to indicate this (it's a game environment that doesn't let me run the async code directly, but from an update call which happens the next frame). Would be easy if I could just put ref on pic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you rephrase the whole thing? Is it related to passbyvalue/passbyreference? That sort of thing?

Comment: Of course it drops the old value, you assigned it to a new one! I don't understand the question either.

Comment: Comment with edit: I'm trying to make it so that pic = picLoading updates picRef when it finished loading.

I'm looking to see if there's a way to do it without referencing the object that picRef is attached to and updating the picture from the object directly. I assume I have to reference picRef's object, but I'm trying to see if there's a way without doing that.

Trying to make that as clear as I can, sorries if it is not.

Comment: Try the ref keyword before the picRef param.

Comment: The way to async loader works (I didn't reference this properly), needs to reference the externally stored pic. I should have written it so that asyncloaderstart also flags another method (asyncLoader) that actually loads picLoading into pic.

Either way, I am just assuming this is an impossible question and have already updated my code to use the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to assign to the original parameter, which seems to be the case based on your code snippet, then you should use the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword in declaration.

```
void AsyncLoadStart(string picLocation, ref Picture picRef)
```

Comment: I'll leave this as the answer as it's good enough for 3/4 of people.

What I actually wanted is pointers, didn't think about them until after I wrote all of this and went "Durr". The issue of not having programed in C++ first and not thinking of pointers as the first thing I guess ^.^ Ref will work for just about everyone else though.